# calculating the total number of rows in a table - fails when it is a heap - is there any fix?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, index-statistics, heap

I have a procedure that I use to find out how big is a table.

```
select * from sys.objects
where name = 'WMS_SLALoad'
-- to get the object_id of my table
-- in this case it is 2041058307

SELECT o.object_id,
       s_name=s.name,
       o.name,
       ddps.row_count 
       ,[Statistics_Updated]=STATS_DATE(I.OBJECT_ID,I.INDEX_ID)
FROM sys.indexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID
  AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
WHERE i.index_id < 2 
  and o.object_id = 2041058307
go
```

[image]

but when I select from that table, there is always 7 rows less.
my count always tell me the table has 7 rows more that it actually has.

one thing I thought might be the case, is this is actually not a table, it is a heap, because it does not have any indexes
as you can see on the script below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WMS_SLALoad](
    [MessageCycleNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Warehouse] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ProdID] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [QuantityChange] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sign] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ReasonCode] [char](2) NULL,
    [InUse] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_WMS_SLALoad_InUse]  DEFAULT (0)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

how can I make sure my script gives me the correct number of rows, whether the object is a table or a heap?

Comment: It may be that the row counts in the system catalog are not correct.  Try running `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(N'dbo.WMS_SLALoad')`.  Also note that unlike `COUNT(*)`, the row count will not be transactionally consistent.

Comment: If you care about 100% accuracy this is not the correct thing to use. (and heaps are tables too)

Comment: @MartinSmith truly though, 100% accuracy is a pipe dream. If the table isn't changing, the DMVs are going to be accurate most of the time. If the table is changing, and so you exclusively lock the entire table to get an accurate count, you're just making those DML transactions wait. The second you release your locks, they're going to take their turn and make all their changes. So how accurate is your count now?

Comment: @AaronBertrand the OP seems concerned about a difference of 7. If that's a problem then this isn't the thing to use. Might as well just use `count`. As the only way of knowing if it is inaccurate would be to count it anyway and fixing it with `updateusage` presumably just counts it anyway.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make use of [DBCC UPDATEUSAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414.aspx)
as mentioned in the comments by  [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman)
has produced the following results:

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(N'WMSData',N'dbo.WMS_SLALoad') WITH COUNT_ROWS
```

[image]

After that the results of my original select was accurate enough for my purposes.